# Layout divs side by side in jQuery tabs

Tags: html, css

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to layout 2 divs next to each other in jQuery tabs. Normally, I just float:left both divs with some styling and they work out of the box. Is there some secret to laying out divs in jQuery tabs.

I would appreciate any help as this is driving me bananas. I have included code which I am experimenting with.Many thanks.

```
<div id="tabContainer">
     <!-- the tabs -->
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">tab4</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">

                <p>Tab1</p>

            <div id="tabRight">This is right div which I need to place next to tabs-1 div</div>

            </div>


            <div id="tabs-2">

                <p>Tab2</p>

            </div>

            <div id="tabs-3">

                <p>Tab3</p>

            </div>

            <div id="tabs-4">

                <p>Tab4</p>

            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS (Minimal)

```
#tabContainer { float: left; padding-bottom: 1px; margin-top:200px;}
#tabs-1 { float:left; }
#tabRight { float:left; }
```

Comment: But you have put the #tabright in a div that is a tab... you can't do that with float, you have to position it absolute. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V5Zrp/. But I suggest restructuring your HTML, because it does not look very good.

Comment: It is in a div that is a tab. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `float: left` to  `<p>Tab1</p>`

I'll suggest to wrap `<p>Tab1</p>` in a div and give `float: left` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two separate divs in #tabs-1 tab.

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div class='tabLeft'>Tab Left</div>
    <div class="tabRight">Tab Right</div>
</div>
```

And give them styling:

```
.tabRight { float:left; }
.tabLeft { float:left; }
```

Comment: Kaverzniy They are appearing one on top of the other. Thanks